# with regard to Vs with reference to Vs in connection with

Tags: phrase-choice

1. The manager wanted to meet you ..............the theft in the office.

A with regard to

B with reference to

C in connection with

For me All are correct, I don't seem any difference b/w their meaning? Dictionary says meaning of "with reference to" means "in connection with something". So they means same.
but I know I am wrong here. Can you explain the difference b/w A, B and C.

Thank you

Comment: I'd opt for a mixture -  **in regard to...**

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "with regard to" indicates that the manager wants to meet you and discuss *directly* the issue of the theft that occurred in the office.

The phrase "With reference to" indicates that the manager wants to meet you and discussing the issue of the theft that occurred in the office.

They both give out the same meaning, but "with regard to" sets off a more urgent tone than "with reference to".

The phrase "In connection with" may or may not indicate that the topic the manager wants to talk to you about is directly about to the theft that occurred in the office.